# authentication problem with SQL when AD user deleted and recreated problem

Tags: sql-server-2005, sid

I have deleted the user from AD and recreated it again with the same display name. Everything works except the SQL since it has a different SID. How can I fix it? I'm afraid to delete the SQL user since it will delete all its entries.

Iyad Jadaa

Answer (score 1):

- [ALTER LOGIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189828(SQL.90).aspx) to change name of current principal
- [CREATE LOGIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189751(SQL.90).aspx) to create new SQL principal
- [ALTER USER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176060(SQL.90).aspx) to remap database rights
- use sys.server_permissions to see server level rights
- DROP LOGIN to remove "old" entry when ready

Answer (score 0):

wow its still there lool 
i fixed it you can delete  each user on the AD has its ID how ever if you use windows authentication for SQL and u recreate the user the SQL program wont recognize the user .
you can delete on SQL and add it again eveything will work perfectly and dont worry it wont delete anything the old user had added to the system